# extract the first number from a string

Tags: bash

I want to extract the first number from a given string.  The number is a float but I only need the integers before the decimal.

example:

```
string1="something34521.32somethingmore3241"
```

Output I want is 34521

What is the easiest way to do this in bash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

So just for simplicity I'll post what I was actually looking for when I got here.

```
echo $string1 | sed 's@^[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*@\1@'
```

Simply skip whatever is not a number from beginning of the string `^[^0-9]*`, then match the number `\([0-9]\+\)`, then the rest of the string `.*` and print only the matched number `\1`.

I sometimes like to use `@` instead of the classical `/` in the `sed` replace expressions just for better visibility within all those slashes and backslashes. Handy when working with paths as you don't need to escape slashes. Not that it matters in this case. Just sayin'.

Comment: Works well. Note that if there is no number, it returns the whole string.

Comment: This pattern looked a bit crazy to me, then I realized you're using sed without the "extended regex" flag. Here's what it looks like with extended regex, much cleaner since you don't need to escape the parenthesis and the plus symbol: `sed -E 's,^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$,\1,'`

Answer (score 6):

There's the awk solution:

```
echo $string1 | awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{ print $2 }'
```

Use -F'[^0-9,]+' to set the field separator to anything that is not a digit (0-9) or a comma, then print it.

Comment: Does not return the first number in case the string starts with the number. For example: `123foo456` would return `456` instead of `123`.

Answer (score 3):

This sed 1 liner will do the job I think:

```
str="something34521.32somethingmore3241"
echo $str | sed -r 's/^([^.]+).*$/\1/; s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/'
```

OUTPUT

```
34521
```

Comment: I like the 1 liner aspect of your answer, BUT read the example data and output OP has provided. Does int() right-remove strings from a value?

Comment: @shellter: When OP originally posted the question it was different and a different sample data was provided. Now since question has been updated so I will need to come up with an alternative answer.

Comment: Bad OP, Bad! Don't change the data! ;-)

Comment: @shellter: lol :) I edited my answer again to suite the changing requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You said you have a string and you want to extract the number, i assume you have other stuff as well.

```
$ echo $string
test.doc_23.001
$ [[ $string =~ [^0-9]*([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+ ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
23

$ foo=2.3
$ [[ $string =~ [^0-9]*([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+ ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
2

$ string1="something34521.32somethingmore3241"
$ [[ $string1 =~ [^0-9]*([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+ ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
34521
```