# Regex to extract the first float number from a string in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, netezza

I am using `$xavg | sed -r 's/^([^.]+).*$/\1/; s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/'` from a previous post at  [extract the first number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811753/extract-the-first-number-from-a-string)
but this gives me only the fraction before the decimal point. I want the first floating point number.

For example :-

"abjhjdw20.39auh201" in this string i want the first floating point number only  20.39

Also in my bash script below:-

```
nzsql -c 'create table Input1(x integer, y integer, v integer)'
nzload -t Input1 -df InputTable.txt

xavg=`nzsql -c 'select avg(x) from Input1'`
echo $xavg | sed -r 's/^([^.]+).*$/\1/; s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/'
aum=xavg
yavg=`nzsql -c 'select avg(y) from Input1'`
echo $yavg | sed -r 's/^([^.]+).*$/\1/; s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/'
nol=yavg
echo $nol
nzsql -c 'select S4(x,y,aum,nol) from test'
```

=======Output Below=======

```
CREATE TABLE
Load session of table 'INPUT1' completed successfully
2
1
yavg

ERROR:  Attribute 'AUM' not found
```

actual average values are 2.3 and 1.6

which are being extracted using the above regex and `nzsql -c 'select S4(x,y,aum,nol) from test'` gives error for 'AUM' but the same value gets printed when i echo it giving 2..

I would be thankful if someone can help me with regex and the error in S4(x,y,aum,nol)

Answer (score 2):

Your sed script only matches up to just before the first decimal point (and at any rate could be simplified).  From your comment below, it seems you only want to process the first line of output from `nzsql` that contains a number.  Also, no sed script can edit a shell variable in place (you appear to be trying to do this with `xavg` and `yavg`).

The bits with the variables `nol` and `aum` look superfluous.

Then your last nzsql operation looks like it should have two shell variable substitutions in the SQL.

In sum:

```
nzsql -c 'create table Input1(x integer, y integer, v integer)'
nzload -t Input1 -df InputTable.txt

xavg=`nzsql -c 'select avg(x) from Input1' | sed -nr '/[0-9]/{s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$/\1/p;q}'`
echo $xavg
yavg=`nzsql -c 'select avg(y) from Input1' | sed -nr '/[0-9]/{s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$/\1/p;q}'`
echo $yavg

nzsql -c "select S4(x,y,${xavg},${yavg}) from test"
```

---

EDIT in response to comments - new version of the script incorporating loops and if statements mentioned there:

```
nzsql -c 'create table Input1(a integer, b integer, c integer)'
nzload -t Input1 -df InputTable.txt

for x in a b c
do
    xavg=`nzsql -c "select avg(${x}) from Input1" | sed -nr '/[0-9]/{s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$/\1/p;q}'`
    for y in b c 
    do
        if [[ "${x}" != "${y}" ]]
        then
            yavg=`nzsql -c "select avg(${y}) from Input1" | sed -nr '/[0-9]/{s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$/\1/p;q}'`
            nzsql -c "select S4(${x},${y},${xavg},${yavg}) from Input1"
        else
            echo 1
        fi
    done 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) .it is giving the number after decimal now but also returns an extra 1 appended ..which is resulting in an error..below is the output:-2.000000 1
1.66667 1
ERROR:  'select S4(x,y,2.000000
1,1.66667
1) from Input1'
error                           ^ found "1" (at char 24) expecting `USING' or `')'' or `',''
If only this extra 1 it is returning can be removed 2.000000 1 and 1.66667 1 i think it will run..Please help me with this one and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've made a modification to the sed invocations above - please try again.

Comment: One more question:-I am trying to perform the above operation in a nested for loop,It loops through the columns in table Input1,Shell script-> nzsql -c 'create table Input1(a integer, b integer, c integer)'
nzload -t Input1 -df InputTable.txt
for x in a b c
do
xavg=`nzsql -c 'select avg(x) from Input1' | sed -nr '/[0-9]/{s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$/\1/p;q}'`
for y in b c
do
yavg=`nzsql -c 'select avg(y) from Input1' | sed -nr '/[0-9]/{s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$/\1/p;q}'`
nzsql -c "select S4(x,y,${xavg},${yavg}) from Input1"
done
done
Error continued to the comment below....

Comment: And this is the error it gives ============================== Error: Operation canceled
Error: External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit
See /panfs/panfs.ccr.buffalo.edu/scratch/Netezza_UDA/INPUT1.ANKITDES_DB.nzlog file
Error: Load Failed, records not inserted.
ERROR:  Attribute 'X' not found
ERROR:  Attribute 'Y' not found
ERROR:  'select S4(x,y,,) from Input1'
error                  ^ found "," (at char 15) expecting identifier found a keyword

Comment: You weren't properly substituting the column name into the calls to `nzsql` that feed input to `sed`.  See edits above.

Comment: 1Last doubt.want to put if condition ..if x==y then it should just echo 1 and resume execution to check(like we have continue in java) for pairs in next execution else if x!=y then execute inner S4() functionBelow code:      for y in b c
    do
        if ["$x" -ne "$y"];then
        yavg=`nzsql -c "select avg(${y}) from Input1" | sed -nr '/[0-9]/{s/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$/\1/p;q}'`
        nzsql -c "select S4(${x},${y},${xavg},${yavg}) from Input1"
        echo "value for combination" $x $y 
        else
        if["$x" -eq "$y"]
        echo $1
        fi
        
    done

Comment: `if` statement added above.

Comment: Actually now i want a regex which can give me the second float number ..for example in this input -- 23.89 44.63 ..I have an input file which has this data and i want the second number after space.So for xample in the first line i want the number after 0,1followed by space and then the number i want to extract that is --->0.7302967433402214              0,1     0.7302967433402214
0,2     0.12909944487358055
0,3     0.0
1,2     0.0
1,3     -0.13245323570650439
2,3     -0.936585811581694